# Different NSDate for same timestapm on ios versions (ios 6 and iOS7)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I ran into this weird issue where one of the method in my code is returning different dates for same timestamp value in different ios version.

Following is the code for that method.

```
+(NSDate *)getDateFromTheTimeStampAsDate:(NSInteger)timeStamp
{
    NSLog(@"Timestamp - %d",timeStamp);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"PST"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM DD,yyyy"];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp]]];
}
```

For timestamp = 1361581013 following are the NSDates values returned from above function:

iOS6 - 2013/02/01
iOS7 - 2013/02/22

Is there anything wrong with this code ?

**Update**: I forgot to look at the date format, earlier. Thanks to one of the comment I managed to get correct date. This was a part of legacy code so in the decided to just trash it and use following:

```
 [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
```

Comment: Please give examples of the output.

Comment: Why does your method create a date formatter which is not used at all?

Comment: @undo: I added output.

Comment: @MartinR: Sorry I just updated.

Comment: Why do you convert `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp]` to a string and back to a date? - And `DD` should probably be `dd` for "day of the month".

Comment: Uh, that date format does not produce the date string  you're showing.  Show us the *real* date format and *real* output.

Comment: (I'm betting your real date format uses YYYY rather than yyyy or some such.)

Comment: (Yeah, DD is "day of year" and clearly incorrect.  *Always* refer  to [the spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) if you're the slightest bit unsure about the format.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I forgot to take a look at date format. Thanks for pointer.

Comment: Date format "MMM DD,yyyy" would produce something like "Feb 54,2012".  You claim you're getting "2013/02/22".  I won't say you're lying, but you're not telling the truth.

Comment: Note that 1361581013 is [Sat, 23 Feb 2013 00:56:53 GMT](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

Answer (score 0):

First the output isn't ever close  to the date.  On the terminal try date -r 1361581013.  At least then you can see if you are getting close.

Second, convert the timestamp to an NSDate. Log that see if its close.

```
    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1361581013] ;
    NSLog(@"d = %@" , d) ;
```

Third after you know you are getting the NSDate then apply formats to it.

```
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;

    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST" ];
    NSLog(@"d with formatting 1 = %@" , [df stringFromDate:d]) ;

    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST" ];
    NSLog(@"d with formatting 1 = %@" , [df stringFromDate:d]) ;

    df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT" ];
    NSLog(@"d with formatting 1 = %@" , [df stringFromDate:d]) ;
```

Then you will know you got it right.

```
d = 2013-02-23 00:56:53 +0000
d with formatting 1 = February 22, 2013 at 4:56:53 PM PST
d with formatting 1 = February 22, 2013 at 7:56:53 PM EST
d with formatting 1 = February 23, 2013 at 12:56:53 AM GMT
```